# Django styling multichoicefield checkboxes

Tags: django

I was able to include multi select checkboxes however, I am having trouble to provide styling to the forms. I can can correctly displaying the options but they appear with a dot in front. When I add a class to the template adding attributes to the widget it adds the class but its not allowing style changes. I try to do it with django widget tweeks and it does not do it either. I think to style the label of the checkbox the class should be inserted to the checkbox label and not to the input.

forms.py

```
 CHOICES = (
    ('a', 'A'),
    ('b', 'b'),
    ('c', 'c'),

)

 class Modalities(forms.Form):
    multicheck = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs={'class': 'check_label'}
    ),
    choices=CHOICES)
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Options</h3>
                    </div>


                    {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field }}
                    {% endfor %}

                    </div>
```

CSS

```
label {
    font: bold 15px "Helvetica Neue";
    text-transform: lowercase;

}

.check_label {
  font: 12px  "Helvetica Neue" !important;
  text-transform: initial !important;


}
```

Output: 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dot in question is because your checkboxes are inside a `<li>` element, the dot is not part of the checkbox input itself..

If you wanted it to be removed, you could either wrap your entire form with a class, and then add:

`.bulletless-form ul li {
    list-style: none;
}`

or do the same for every field id manually.

Alternativelly, write your own widget for the checkbox, that would render it without a list.